# Problem in implementing ValueEventListeners

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

In the below code, I'm doing is what I am checking whether EventsRef dataSnapshot exists or not, if dataSnapshot exists = I am getting some values and storing it in a list and passing that list values to recyclerView method ,in that it displays those values, and my problem is if 2 users in online and both of them getting displayed those details , if user1 removes that reference from firebase database by deleting that event, user2 getting error and getting out of the application . I used child event listener as in the below code but it doesn't works as well . and if i use if else condtions inside the child event listener inside on child Added it also doesn't works , So please help me to solve this both issues .Thanks in advance.

```
EventsRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
        {
            if (dataSnapshot.exists())
            {
                EventsRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s)
                    {
                        EventsRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
                            {
                                if (dataSnapshot.exists())
                                {
                                    for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
                                    {
                                        String eventId = ds.child("Eid").getValue(String.class);
                                        String gender = ds.child("Gender").getValue(String.class);
                                        String serveCount = ds.child("Serve").getValue(String.class);

                                        list.add(eventId);
                                        list2.add(gender);
                                        list3.add(serveCount);

                                    }

                                    if (list.size() != 0)
                                    {
                                        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
                                        {
                                            RecyclerView(list.get(i), list2.get(i), list3.get(i));
                                        }
                                    }


                                }
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                            }
                        });
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(WorkerMyEventActivity.this, "Event removed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
            }
            else
            {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt);
                txt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

[image]

Comment: Could you give a snapshot of your data structure. Listener within a listener may not be a good idea

Comment: Its the one who gets in the recylerview method . If the user fetching the data in online by child event listener which is in the code above . If the admin deletes that reference the user getting error message and comes out of the application.

Comment: My only moto is if user displaying the events in their phone ,at the same time if admin removes that reference from the database i don't want to show any error